# Find highest values in n unequal lists

Tags: python, list

I have list with `n` multiple lists.

```
data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [2, 6, 3, 5, 9, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5],
    [8, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5]
    [3, 9, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 9, 3]
]
```

How can I efficiently compare them and generate a list which always contains the highest value at the current position?
I don't know how I can do this since the boundaries for each list are different.

The output for the above example should be a list with these values:

```
[8,9,4,5,9,6,7,8,9,4,5]
```

Comment: Will the numbers always be >= 0?

Comment: Do you accept pandas' answer ?

Comment: @n00b.exe , I don't want that you should accept my answer , please remove accept mark from there.

Comment: I accepted @C0LDSPEED's Answer. But all of you helped me a lot !

Comment: @n00b.exe that was my main purpose for giving answer to your question , just understand the logic and then use any lib or module :)

Comment: Sometimes, that can be counter-intuitive. ^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most idiomatic approach would be transposing the 2D list and calling `max` on each row in the transposed list. But in your case, you're dealing with *ragged lists*, so `zip` cannot be directly applied here (it zips upto the shortest list only).

Instead, use `itertools.zip_longest` (`izip_longest` for python 2), and then apply `max` using `map` -

```
from itertools import zip_longest
r = list(map(max, zip_longest(*data, fillvalue=-float('inf'))))
```

Or, using [@Peter DeGlopper's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156643/find-highest-values-in-n-unequal-lists/48156692#comment83292333_48156692), with a list comprehension -

```
r = [max(x) for x in zip_longest(*data, fillvalue=-float('inf'))]
```

```
print(r)
[8, 9, 4, 5, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5]
```

Here, I use a `fillvalue` parameter to fill missing values with negative infinity. The intermediate result looks something like this -

```
list(zip_longest(*data, fillvalue=-float('inf')))

[(1, 2, 8, 3),
 (2, 6, 1, 9),
 (3, 3, 4, 1),
 (4, 5, 1, 2),
 (5, 9, 2, 2),
 (6, 1, 3, 1),
 (7, 1, 4, 1),
 (8, 1, 2, 5),
 (-inf, 2, 5, 9),
 (-inf, 4, -inf, 3),
 (-inf, 5, -inf, -inf)]
```

Now, applying `max` becomes straightforward - just do it over each row and you're done.

Comment: I prefer a comprehension over `list(map(...))`: eg `r = [max(candidates) for candidates in itertools.izip_longest(*data, fillvalue=float('-inf'))]` - but this is basically what I had in my edit widget.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Thanks, that's a good suggestion, I appreciate it.

Comment: I guess the list comp is a little more readable than using `list` and `map`, but IMHO `map` is ok here because you're calling `max`, a built-in function written in C. OTOH, using `map` or `filter` with a `lambda` is not so efficient because it involves an extra Python function call per iteration compared to using a list comp.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, that was helpful. I'm okay with `map` and `filter` as long as its with an inbuilt function. I've been conditioned not to use lambdas as much as possible. :-)

Comment: I prefer comprehensions for style reasons, I don't think I've ever had a case where I had reason to measure the performance of them vs `map` or `filter`. Built-ins when possible is always good advice, eg IIRC I saw about a 10% speedup from using `itemgetter`/`attrgetter` rather than a lambda to define a custom `sort` key.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I tend to agree. `map` (in Python 3) is great when you can use a generator, but a list comp is more readable (unless you're coming from a functional language like Haskell). However, `map` _is_ noticeably faster, especially in Python 3, see [here](https://pastebin.com/2HBrcws1) for some `timeit` code.

Answer (score 2):

[zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) is your friend in this case.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [2, 6, 3, 5, 9, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5],
    [8, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5],
    [3, 9, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 9, 3],
]

output = list()

for x in zip_longest(*data, fillvalue=0):
  output.append(max(x))

print(output)
>>> [8, 9, 4, 5, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `pandas` solution

```
import pandas as pd 

pd.DataFrame(data).max().astype(int).tolist()
Out[100]: [8, 9, 4, 5, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Nice one! Like this.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ hah ,Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.izip_longest` (`itertools.zip_longest` in Python3):

Python2:

```
import itertools
data = [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
[2, 6, 3, 5, 9, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5],
[8, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5],
[3, 9, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 9, 3],
]
new_data = [max(filter(lambda x:x, i)) for i in itertools.izip_longest(*data)]
```

Output:

```
[8, 9, 4, 5, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5]
```

Python3:

```
import itertools
data = [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
[2, 6, 3, 5, 9, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5],
[8, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5],
[3, 9, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 9, 3],
]
new_data = [max(filter(None, i)) for i in itertools.zip_longest(*data)]
```

Comment: `filter(None, i)`

Comment: You're right about `zip_longest` but I think your `filter` does a little too much. That will drop 0 from the list, which is maybe safe here (all the sample data is positive integers) but I'd prefer not to get into the habit when working with numeric data. I like specifying the fill value as something that can never be the max, but `filter(lambda x: x is not None, i)` would be safer if you want to use the default behavior of filling with `None` and then filter that out.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Yep, good point. The filter removes falsey values, including 0 and 0.0. This could even result in a `ValueError` being thrown if `max` ever receives an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any external module , Just use some logic and you go :

```
data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [2, 6, 3, 5, 9, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5],
    [8, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5],
    [3, 9, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 9, 3]
]

new_data={}
for j in data:
    for k,m in enumerate(j):
        if k not in new_data:
            new_data[k] = [m]
        else:
            new_data[k].append(m)




final_data=[0]*len(new_data.keys())

for key,value in new_data.items():
    final_data[key]=max(value)

print(final_data)
```

output:

```
[8, 9, 4, 5, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I don't see your point. `itertools` is not an external module, you just need to import it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I see the benefit in rewriting the same thing that can be succinctly achieved by a function, for the sake of "simplicity" (where is the simplicity here?)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , I never downvote and i never expect upvote nor i give answer for upvote or downvote. Thanks for comment. I am not in race of earning points , I just enjoy  coding :)

Comment: I guess it's good to show how to perform this transposition using explicit loops and an extra collection (`new_data`), but I bet `zip_longest` is faster. Note that `itertools` is (usually) compiled into the CPython interpreter, so importing it doesn't even require an extra disk access. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names and run `import sys; sys.builtin_module_names` to get a list of those modules.

Comment: @PM2Ring i agree with your point , but where i mentioned anything with time? I just wanted to show some handmade logic , but sometimes people take it in harsh way :)